# Returning directory of containing file

Tags: r

Is there command in R which would return the full directory path to the file containing the code being executed, similar to PHP's [`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)?

Comment: How are you executing the code?

Comment: Maybe `getwd()` is what you're looking for?  But answering Joshua would help!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich - I'm using [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three answers, none of them probably completely satisfactory to you, since the R execution model is different than the PHP one.  This is in order: a) the location of the R executable, b) the location of the default directory for sourcing files, and c) the locations where R will search for installed packages if an unambiguous location is not given:

```
 R.home()
#[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
 getwd()
#[1] "/Users/davidwinsemius"
 .libPaths()
#[1] "/Users/davidwinsemius/Library/R/2.14/library"                   
#[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.14/Resources/library"
```

I thought of a fourth option that might be what you actually want. If you have started a batch session of R with a CMD invocation then you can recover the args to that command with the first line and (maybe, depending on how you made the call and your OS)  identify the input file with:

```
cmdargs <- commandArgs(TRUE)  
cmdargs["infile"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to call `source` to execute a script with the `chdir=TRUE` argument. Then the script only needs to call `getwd()`. However, this relies on the caller of the script to do the right thing.

Another way is to realize that each function typically saves the source information (it can be disabled). So if you define a function in your script, you could extract the file name from the function instance.

Put the following in "c:/foo.R" (or "/tmp/foo.R" on Linux):

```
whereAmI <- function() attr(attr(whereAmI, 'srcref'), 'srcfile')$filename

fileName <- whereAmI()
cat("Here I am:", fileName, "\n")
cat("In folder:", dirname(fileName), "\n")
```

...Then try it:

```
> source("c:/foo.R")
Here I am: c:/foo.R
In folder: c:/
```

Comment: So that is the randomly generated location of the last function that was byte-compiled?

Comment: Not for me (R 2.14.0), not even if I call `compiler::enableJIT(4)`. Do you get a weird result?

Comment: I got: "Here I am:  /var/folders/xS/xSUsVXTIHEiP7OLJg2OXmU+++TI/-Tmp-//RtmpqeJtDX/file1f9196a0 ". And since that did not involve any call to whereAmI, I assumed it was the location of the last defined function.

Comment: Nope, that's `tmp <- tempfile()`. Try `tmp <- 'c:/foo.R'` or `tmp <- '/tmp/foo.R'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a bit fragile since it depends on the internals of the `source` command (which could change in future versions of R) this line in your sourced file should do it.  It must be directly at the top level in your sourced file and not in a function within your sourced file.

```
this.dir <- dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile)
```