# How to get R script file name when a function in it is called?

Tags: r, function, filenames, plyr

I have several R script files, such as `f1.R`, `f2.R`, `f3.R`.

I have another function called AddSignal(signal), which adds a signal vector to a list. Functions in f1.R, f2.R, etc. may call this AddSignal() function.

Now what I want is that, in function AddSignal(), besides doing the add signal part, it also records which function in which R file made the call. For example, I'd like to know function ff1() in f1.R added signal sig1.

Is there a way to do that?

In fact, using sys.call(), I can know which function (for example, ff1()) called AddSignal(). But I don't know which R file that ff1() is in. I can see a hard way of doing it, is to scan all .R files and then store a mapping of file names and function names. But I'd like to see whether there is an easier way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by a function calling GetFileName?  Do you mean you want to pass your function as a parameter to GetFileName?

Comment: Could you add your reason for doing this to the question? It sounds rather exotic what you want, maybe we can suggest an alternative...

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132150/returning-directory-of-containing-file

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The real application is, I have a function called AddSignals(signal), which adds a signal vector to a list. Each of the f1.R, f2.R has functions that calls AddSignals(). But besides signal itself, I want to know which function added that signal (which is easy to get using sys.call()), and I want to know in which file that function is. For example, I want to know function ff1() in file f1.R added signal sig1.

Comment: You can use sys.source to attach new position to search path with name same as sourced file. Then you can find this name using function find("f1").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I would do is create a lookup table which maps a function to the `.R` file it is in. You have to recreate this table every time you add, remove, or move a function, but I think it would be preferable to regenerating the table every time you want to find the source file of a function. So here is my take on create such a table:

```
library(plyr)

functionsFromRfile = function(filename) {
# Get all functions from a source file. Create new enviroment
# source the functions into them and use ls() to extract names.
  e = new.env()
  source(filename, local = e)
  return(ls(envir = e))
}

# This assumes you are in the directory with your R code,
# and that all files need to be included. You can also
# make this list manually ofcourse
Rfiles = list.files(".", pattern = ".R")
# Get a list of functions for each .R file
lutFunc2sourcefile = ldply(Rfiles, function(x) {
  return(data.frame(fname = x, func = functionsFromRfile(x)))
})
```

For one of my own packages this leads to:

```
> head(lutFunc2sourcefile)
               fname                func
1 autofitVariogram.r    autofitVariogram
2     autoKrige.cv.r        autoKrige.cv
3     autoKrige.cv.r checkIfautokrige.cv
4     autoKrige.cv.r          compare.cv
5     autoKrige.cv.r   cv.compare.bubble
6     autoKrige.cv.r   cv.compare.ggplot
```

You can use the lookup table to performing the mapping using the function name obtained from `sys.call`.

**EDIT**: In view of your comment on non-function code, this code uses parse, which does not evaluate the code. It searches through the output of parse, and weeds out the functions, and should not evaluate any code or return code that is not a function. I haven't tested it exhaustively, give it a try.

```
library(plyr)

Rfiles = list.files(".", pattern = "(.R|.r)")
lutFunc2sourcefile = ldply(Rfiles, function(fname) {
   f = parse(fname)
   functions = sapply(strsplit(as.character(f), "="), function(l) {
     if(grepl("^function", sub(' ', '', l[2]))) {
       return(l[1])
     } else {
       return(NA)
     }
    })
   return(data.frame(fname, func = functions))  
})
# Remove lines with func = NA
lutFunc2sourcefile = lutFunc2sourcefile[!is.na(lutFunc2sourcefile$func),]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My R files are in fact in a library. I wonder whether there is an easier way for library.

Comment: In a library, all functions are in the /R subdir. Just point the call to list.files to that directory and your done. Do take into account that if you use list.files in anything other than the current workdir, use full.names = TRUE.

Comment: Thanks. The only worry is that some files may have code that can run, instead of just functions. Then sourcing them would do something, or more concerning, it may take unknown time to run or gives error.

Comment: That would also be a problem when loading the package, that code would also be executed then. I don't think that having non-function code in a package is a good idea.

Comment: I added a second solution which uses parse, this should work also in case of non-function code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra work. I do agree that non-function code in a package is a good idea, but just trying to be careful as nothing prevents that. In your new code, I like the parse function. But most of the time I would use "<-" instead of "=". So the strsplit part may need to change a little bit. But in general I think this is as good as I can get from anyone. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you could modify `AddSignal(signal)` to

```
AddSignal(signal, filename=NULL){
  ...
  ...
  return(list(signal=signal,filename=filename))}
```

Comment: Is this a rethorical question which is meant to answer to the question of this page with a solution? In that case I recommend to rephrase into a more assertive answer. Otherwise people mistake this for a clarification question and flag as "Should be a comment, is not an answer." If you DO want to ask for clarification before actually answering, then please use your commenting privilege.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn <- commandArgs()[4]

filename <- strsplit(fn, "=")[[1]][2]

cat(filename)
```

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate your answer please? Add some text to comment the way your code works and why you wrote it as given. It will be of better value and friendlier to other users, especially those not expert in R.